# Can an innerclass also be a subclass and also

Tags: java

Can a innerclass also be a subclass.  Also one more thing in this set of java planguage it's not allowing me to create a instance of subclass even though I already created a instance of my encapsulating class for the innerclass.

```
public class Main {

Main OpTypes[] = new Main[3];

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Main c = new Main();
    c.OpTypes[0] = new Division(6,3);
    Jool x = new Jool();
}

public class Jool { 
    public Jool() { 

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Since you have 98% of the code, what happened when you tried it (by using `extends`)?

Comment: it's a innerclass so I'm thinking is there really any point to add extend for inheritance and when I did add extends to Jool it still has a error.

Comment: Well, what is the error? (Do *search* for this error as well and see if any of the results apply - at least one will.)

Comment: I tried adding extends to public class jool for inheritance but it doesn't work and also what's the point of it if it's a innerclass - doesn't it inherit from main anyway since it's a innerclass.

Comment: An nested class *does not* implicitly inherit from the containing class. However there are special rules to be able to access the enclosing instance variables from within inner class. These rules do *not* mean that the inner class 'is a' (or 'extends') the outer class.

Comment: WHy are you wasting time here when you can test it for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If you try it, you'll find that an inner class *can* extend a class.

Also, since the inner class is *not* `static`, it requires an instance of the outer class when constructing it. In the code below, you'll see two ways of doing that.

Method `test` shows the most common way, which is to do it from an instance (non-static) method of the outer class, in which case the outer class is implicit.

Method `main` shows how to do it outside of an instance method of the outer class, in which case you have to give an outer class instance before the `new` operator.

```
class MyBaseClass {
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Main c = new Main();
        Jool x = c.new Jool(); // "c" explicitly used as outer class instance
    }

    public void test() { 
        Jool x = new Jool(); // "this" implicitly used as outer class instance
    }

    public class Jool extends MyBaseClass { // Inner class extends unrelated class
    }

}
```